# PowerPack printform produce an incorrect postscript file

Tags: windows-7, printform, vb-power-pack

I am using again a VB10 application a write months ago who produce postscript files through printform object and powerpack. It has always worked well.
But the ps files I write now are incorrect, or at least not recognized by Paintshop who give the following message: undefined in HP-PCL. 
I guess that the problem is I have upgraded from XP to Win7 ...
Any idea what can I do ?
thanks in advance 
David Remotti

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution, so I think it's good to share it.
The problem was simply the default printer. For some reason it was defined as an old HP printer that I do not have anymore. So it has been enough to define PDFcreator as the default printer to have back my nice postscript files.